# eclipse maven repositories are grayed out

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've tried many ways in two days, but I can't solve this.Help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YgOJ.png)

Comment: Why shouldn't they be grayed out? What's your problem preventing you to do what?

Comment: Even if I right-click, the rebuild index does not appear. Build is possible normally, but the add dependency function is not available for repository

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/914

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse extracts this data directly from your **settings.xml**

< **localRepository** >C:/Users/username/.m2/repository < /**localRepository**>

You will not be able to change this on the IDE.